# Can not initialize irepository<> generic

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I defined and implemented `IRepository`, `IEntity` code as below.

```
//define Repository
public interface IRepository {}
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    TEntity Insert(TEntity entity);
}
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity, int> where TEntity : class, IEntity<int> { }
public class Repository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    public TEntity Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        return entity;
    }
}
public class Repository<TEntity> : Repository<TEntity, int> where TEntity : class, IEntity<int> { }
public interface IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    TPrimaryKey Id { get; set; }
}

//define entity
public interface IEntity : IEntity<int> { }
public abstract class Entity : Entity<int>, IEntity { }
public abstract class Entity<TPrimaryKey> : IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    public virtual TPrimaryKey Id { get; set; }
}

//customer
public class Customer : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

when i try to create initialize a `Repository<customer>()`

```
IRepository<Customer> repository = new Repository<Customer>();
```

I got this error:

> 'Infrastructure.Repository.Repository'
>   to
>   'Infrastructure.Repository.IRepository'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

But when i use code above, it works.

```
IRepository<Customer,int> repository = new Repository<Customer>();
```

i thought `IRepository<customer,int>` is equal to `IRepository<customer>`
What is the problem when initial a repository like this:

```
IRepository<Customer> repository = new Repository<Customer>();
```

Comment: It doesn't look like Repository<TEntity> implements IRepository<TEntity> at all.It only implements IRepository<TEntity, TKey>?

Comment: Thanks! I will never find this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Reasurria in the comments, your `Repository<TEntity>` class does not inherit from `IRepository<TEntity>` so the compiler cannot perform an implicit conversion between them. You need to update your class definition to include the missing interface:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : Repository<TEntity, int>, IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity<int> { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this can solve your problem:
When i test your code like this

```
IRepository<Customer> repository =(IRepository<Customer>) new Repository<Customer>();
```

Casting to IRepository, the error has gone. Maybe the compiler don`t know what to do because you have 2 declarations of`Repository` class.